# Special character in text field

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am getting ID card number form user in text field. The format of ID card number is like

```
36459-6523698-5
```

I want that as user types 36459 automatically - is inserted in text field and so on.

Comment: There are a ***huge*** number of pitfalls here (not least that you're going to surprise the user, and users don't like to be surprised -- I know I'm always having to backspace because I type the hyphen and end up with two, and while you could handle that *too*, it gets messy, fast). If you really want to do it, strongly recommend using a plug-in someone's already written and debugged for you, like (no endorsement, don't know it) the one @Krule pointed you at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a masked input plugin: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ or https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

Comment: That's gorgeous, and even handles copy & paste correctly. If one absolutely *has* to do it, looks like quite a good one.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use a plugin, you can do this:

```
   $('#card').keyup(function() {
    var card = $(this).val();
    var format = "#####-######-#";
    var i = card.length;
    var output = format.substring(0,1);
    var text   = format.substring(i)
    if (text.substring(0,1) != output) $(this).val(card + text.substring(0,1));
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/lfrias/KN4jt/

OBS: You have to limit the maxlength

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check onkeyup against a regular expression and if a match insert a hyhpen (-).

Or even better, use a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a MaskedTextBox and set the mask you need instead of a normal TextBox control.

Example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx

Comment: The tags on the question are `jquery` `html` and `ajax`. What does ASP.Net have to do with it?

Comment: @T.J Crowder, thanks for clarifying. I did reference to ASP.NET because there should be a "similar" way to do it in jquery, html, ajax or any other technology. This has been proved by Krule's answer above.